# Bot after deploing to server on debian doesn't work withou threaded (telebot, python)

Tags: python

i cache the problem, sense of this problem is bot, which doesn't work without arg `threaded`, anyone have a solution for this problem?
Server Linux Ubuntu 18.04 / centos 8 (both doesn't work) on first clear uwsgi on second uwsgi + nginx, and bot work with threaded, but without not.
I want achieve that my bot can work in threaded mode, i don't have errors and others, if i start my bot without parametr threaded (default it true)

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('my_token')
```

The string which i demonstrate under (i mark it <----):

```
@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update,])   #    <---- THIS STRING
        bot.send_message(update.message.from_user.id, update.message.text)
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)
```

Doesn't work, and from this all of my other code doesn't work, because it's method let start the query to handle of all my others handlers, but this not happening because threaded is True, if i set this parametr in false it's work, but it's work not so good and I want so help to solve this problem.
I finded description([github forum](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/438#issuecomment-353843637)) why it's not work, but my host VDSINA and i same have one thread, maybe it's a problem?
My uwsgi configuration:

```
[uwsgi]

socket = 127.0.0.1:9090 
#shared-socket = :9090
#https = =0,webhook_cert.pem,webhook_pkey.pem
wsgi-file = foobar.py 
callable = app
master = true 
processes = 4 
threads = 2
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
```

But how I change this and how many time, I don't get the solve.
All code of my bot:

```
from flask import Flask
import flask
from time import sleep
import logging
import telebot


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("simple output")
    return "<span style='color:red'>I am app 1</span>"

bot = telebot.TeleBot('my_tok')
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
API_TOKEN = bot.token

WEBHOOK_HOST = 'ip_my_serve'
# nginx # WEBHOOK_PORT = 8443  # 443, 80, 88 or 8443 (port need to be 'open')
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'  # In some VPS you may need to put here the IP addr

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = '/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt'  # Path to the ssl certificate
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = '/etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key'  # Path to the ssl private key

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (API_TOKEN)

bot.remove_webhook()

sleep(1)

bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,
                certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))


@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update,])
        bot.send_message(update.message.from_user.id, update.message.text)
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your question? What do you want to achieve? What is the error message?

Comment: I added more details to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solve for this answer it's change uwsgi on cherrypy, and it's my solution.